# get the top 100 crypto coins for momentum ranked portfolio

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i would like to build a momentum ranked portfolio and need the top 100 or even top 200 crypto coins in my script. just like here:

https://www.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/

as they the top 100 is dynamic i would like to put the names in an array and then work with it. i legit cant find a way to to get the top 100 list. i am not a coder, can python just a bit and am coding for 1 month in pine, so excuse my noobish question

thanks buddies!

Answer (score 0):

You can request data from different assets by using the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function.

For example, below code gets the close price of ETH/USDT and ADA/USDT:

```
close_eth = security("BINANCE:ETHUSDT", timeframe.period, close)
close_ada = security("BINANCE:ADAUSDT", timeframe.period, close)
```

However, the number of security calls you can have in your script is [limited to 40](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/appendix/Pine_compilation_errors.html#script-requesting-too-many-securities).

So, you cannot really scan 100 coins with one script. You either need to narrow down your coin list, or add the same script multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am well aware of the function but the top 100 is dynamic and I want the top 100 ordered by market cap in a script on a continuous basis. And then I rank them basesed on their momentum. Would not mind doing only the top 40 but it's changing order and the security function is static. I want a set and forget script

Comment: Is there maybe a function where I can get the top coin data from the exchanges?

Comment: Oh, I see. No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Good question and a feature that would be useful!

I don't have an answer to your question directly but I put together a script earlier where you visually can compare momentum of ETH and BTC against other categories such as DeFi and L1's. And also to see if "Is it all beta, anon" :)

Check it out here: https://www.tradingview.com/script/YGade0Nx-Dusty-Cluster/